# IntelliJ Code Templates

Tags: java, templates, variables, intellij-idea

I was wondering if it is possible to create code templates with IntelliJ. I would like to save my getInstance() method into a variable, or something along those lines, and while I'm coding, can use the variable to generate my getInstance() method. Is this possible? If so how?

Thanks again,
 Niknea.

Answer (score 3):

There are live templates which you can create.

Settings->Live Templates

There are lots of existing live templates already. Just add a new one.

For ex.:
'iter' is a already defined live template. When you code you just can type 'iter' (without quotes) and then press the tab button. This will produce a for loop.

Comment: `psvm` will produce `public static void main` :-) I didn't knew about what you said in this answer. Happy to know this thingy too, just started using `IntelliJ IDEA` :-) +1

Comment: hmm, I created a template called "test", disputing the code "test". However, when I type "test" in my code, and press tab, I get the code "ResolverUtil.Test" not the text "test".

Comment: Maybe you forgot to define the language. Below the code you typed, you can define the languages in which this live template should be available.

Comment: where is the define option? EDIT: I figured it out, however is there a way to get the class name in the live template? As i would like to define an instance variable named the class name its created in.

Comment: just below the textarea where you define the code. I do have IntelliJ 13.3.1. If you have different version it might be somewhere else.

Comment: I found an example [here](http://www.mograblog.com/2012/02/my-list-of-useful-intellij-live.html). take a look at the last example. I actually don't use the live templates very much. I just know that they exist :-)

Answer (score 1):

You already have it (at least in the new versions of IntelliJ): use the shortcut: `geti` (and press tab). Tested successfully on IntelliJ 13.0.3

ottrob pointed where it's defined: under "Live Templates" click the "Other" section and when it's expended you should see it defined as the first item.